# Pass php callback with one argument

Tags: php, callback

I made a function, which accepts one argument. I need to pass a callback to this function with a string argument.
like this:

```
class AdminHelper {
    static function print_checkbox($option_name){
        $value_cpt_manager=esc_attr(get_option($option_name ));
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$option_name.'" class="regular-text" value="'.$value_cpt_manager.'" placeholder="Your First name" >';
    }
}
add_settings_field( "cpt_manager", "First Name", 
       [AdminHelper::class,'print_checkbox'],  "main_menu", "MainSettings_section1", ['label_for'=>"MainSettings"."1",'class'=>'cpt_manager'] );
```

[AdminHelper::class,'print_checkbox'] would be the callback, but i cant find how i can give it a string argument.
So something like [AdminHelper::class,'print_checkbox',"param"]

Comment: So this is WordPress, yes? I don’t get what you are actually trying to do here. But I think the only way to get this done, would be to use a helper function, that calls `AdminHelper::print_checkbox` _with_ the intended parameter value, and then specify that function as the callback in the add_settings_field call. Question would be, do you win anything by that - then the option name would still have to be hard-coded in that secind function, so … probably not? But again, rather unclear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: yep, i want to create callback functions for different type of fields, like checkbox, then i just pass the option_name to it and it prints an input checkbox, so that i dont repeat "echo<input name="option_name".." every time. The add_settings_field uses the callback to print the setting, so thats why i want to pass a name to that callback.

Comment: That is not directly possible using PHP’s callback mechanism. As said, I think the only way to do this, would be to use wrapper functions. But then you would still need to create a wrapper function for each option name. With anonymous functions, you could do that in a loop of course.